# Automatically change symbol modified in style manager using QGIS3

Tags: qgis-3, style

I used Style Manager to add some symbols.
Then I assigned them to a feature/layer.

But if I change the Symbol / style (only via style editor), the layer will not change automatically.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What is the "symbol editor"? I'm not aware of any QGIS feature or tool by that name, and it's not showing up in a google search.

Comment: Did you mean Style Manager instead of Symbol Editor?

Comment: oh sorry, yes i mean style manager.